# Сигналы и слоты не работают :(

Tags: qt, сигналы-слоты

В общем не работают сигналы и слоты , не знаю что прям делать чтоб заработали :(

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QHostAddress>

//#include <QRegExpValidator> not work in ubuntu 20 ;_;
#include <QValidator>

#include <QIntValidator>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QString string_no_probel(QString &str);
     // юдипи сокеты
    QUdpSocket* m_pudp;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_pB_open_clicked();
    void slotSendDatagram(int port_udp);
    void slotProcessDatagrams();
    void on_pB_send_clicked();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    m_pudp = new QUdpSocket(this);

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lE_enoverport->setValidator(new QIntValidator(ui->lE_enoverport));
    ui->lE_localport->setValidator(new QIntValidator(ui->lE_localport));
    //    ui->lE_localport->setMaxLength(10);
    //    ui->lE_localport->setMaxLength(10);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pB_open_clicked()
{
     //  локальный порт

     QString str_localport = ui->lE_localport->text();
     string_no_probel(str_localport);

    int int_localport = str_localport.toInt();
//    qDebug() << "int_localport :" << int_localport;

    // удалённый порт

    QString str_enoverport = ui->lE_enoverport->text();
    string_no_probel(str_enoverport);

    int int_enoverport = str_enoverport.toInt();

//    m_pudp = new QUdpSocket(this);
    
     m_pudp->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, int_localport);
     connect(m_pudp, SIGNAL(ui->pB_open->clicked()), this, SLOT(slotSendDatagram(int_enoverport)));  // otpravka датаграмму
//    connect(m_pudp, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotProcessDatagrams(int_localport)));
//    connect(m_pudp, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this, SLOT(slotError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

//    connect(m_pudp, &MainWindow::on_pB_send_clicked, this, &MainWindow::slotSendDatagram(int_enoverport));  // otpravka датаграмму
    connect(m_pudp, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::slotProcessDatagrams);
    connect(m_pudp, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this, SLOT(slotError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
}

QString MainWindow::string_no_probel(QString &str)
{
    int n = str.size() - 1;
    for ( ; n >= 0; -- n){
            if (str.at(n) == ' ' )
                str.remove(n, 1 );
    }
        return str;
}

void MainWindow::slotSendDatagram(int port_udp)
{
    QByteArray baDatagram;
    QDataStream out(&baDatagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);
//    QString otpravka = "я: " + ui->lE_localport->text();
    ui->textBrowser->append("я: " + ui->lE_message->text());

    out <<  ui->lE_message->text();
    ui->lE_message->clear(); //pobolansi imi

    m_pudp->writeDatagram(baDatagram, QHostAddress::LocalHost, port_udp);
}

void MainWindow::on_pB_send_clicked()
{
}

void MainWindow::slotProcessDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray baDatagram;
    do {
        baDatagram.resize(m_pudp->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_pudp->readDatagram(baDatagram.data(), baDatagram.size());
    } while(m_pudp->hasPendingDatagrams());

    QDataStream in(&baDatagram, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);
    QString str_priem;
    in >>  str_priem;

    ui->textBrowser->append("принятое :" + str_priem);
}
```

**вывод**

```
20:36:24: Запускается /home/comp/dima/Qt/udipiclientserver/udipiclientserver ...
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such signal QUdpSocket::ui->pB_open->clicked()
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such signal QUdpSocket::error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

Comment: по первой ошибке — на сокет очень сложно кликнуть... разве что силовой розетке щелбан дать... по второй — имя сигнала  `errorOccurred()`, а не `error()`... и в чём смысл использования классического синтаксиса `connect()` вместо нового?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Fat-Zer

вот код :

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QHostAddress>

//#include <QRegExpValidator> not work in ubuntu 20 ;_;
#include <QValidator>

#include <QIntValidator>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QString string_no_probel(QString &str);
     // юдипи сокеты
    QUdpSocket* m_pudp;

    int int_enoverport;
    int int_localport;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_pB_open_clicked();
    void slotSendDatagram(int port_udp);
    void slotProcessDatagrams();
// signals:
//    void on_pB_send_clicked();

    void on_pB_send_clicked();
    void on_pB_close_clicked();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    int_enoverport = 0;
    int_localport = 0;

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lE_enoverport->setValidator(new QIntValidator(ui->lE_enoverport));
    ui->lE_localport->setValidator(new QIntValidator(ui->lE_localport));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pB_open_clicked()
{
    //  локальный порт

    QString str_localport = ui->lE_localport->text();
    string_no_probel(str_localport);

    int_localport = str_localport.toInt();

    // удалённый порт

    QString str_enoverport = ui->lE_enoverport->text();
    string_no_probel(str_enoverport);

    int_enoverport = str_enoverport.toInt();

    m_pudp = new QUdpSocket(this);
    m_pudp->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, int_localport);

    connect(m_pudp, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotProcessDatagrams()));
    connect(m_pudp, SIGNAL(disconnected()), m_pudp, SLOT(deleteLater()));
}

QString MainWindow::string_no_probel(QString &str)
{
    int n = str.size() - 1;
    for ( ; n >= 0; -- n){
        if (str.at(n) == ' ' )
            str.remove(n, 1 );
    }
    return str;
}

void MainWindow::slotSendDatagram(int port_udp)
{
    QByteArray baDatagram;
    QDataStream out(&baDatagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);
    //    QString otpravka = "я: " + ui->lE_localport->text();
    ui->textBrowser->append("я: " + ui->lE_message->text());

    out <<  ui->lE_message->text();
    ui->lE_message->clear(); //pobolansi imi

    m_pudp->writeDatagram(baDatagram, QHostAddress::LocalHost, port_udp);
}

void MainWindow::on_pB_send_clicked()
{
    slotSendDatagram(int_enoverport);
}

void MainWindow::slotProcessDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray baDatagram;
    do {
        baDatagram.resize(m_pudp->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_pudp->readDatagram(baDatagram.data(), baDatagram.size());
    } while(m_pudp->hasPendingDatagrams());

    QDataStream in(&baDatagram, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_3);
    QString str_priem;
    in >>  str_priem;

    ui->textBrowser->append("принятое :" + str_priem);
}

void MainWindow::on_pB_close_clicked()
{
    m_pudp->close();
}
```